# Download complete folder shared under Photos on Dropbox

Tags: dropbox

Is there any way to allow someone to download the whole shared Photos folder on Dropbox and not only individual files? Preferable a solution that doesn't require the receiver to register on Dropbox?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try [this method](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20120719202154343) posted on Mac OS X Hints:

> Just stick the folder of files into your public folder, and head to
>   the Dropbox webapp. Click on the folder you want to share, then click
>   the “Get Link” button at the top of the page. Add ?dl=1 to the end of
>   it, and send that link to your friends. It’ll zip the file up for them
>   and download it to their computer. ([Lifehacker synopsis](http://www.lifehacker.com.au/2012/07/share-multiple-files-from-your-dropbox-folder-without-zipping-them/))

Comment: Wow. Actually I didn't expect this to be possible, but your answer worked like a dream John. Thank you very much!

Comment: no worries! glad I could help :-)

Comment: This only works on folders less than 20GB and containing fewer than a few thousand files.

Answer (score 2):

(As at 17 Oct 2013), When you open the shared folder listing all the images, click on 'Share Link' icon at the top, then click on the 'Get Link' button in the dialog that opens, then click on the round 'tool' icon beside then 'Share' button at the top of the page, then select 'download as .zip'.